# JavaScript REGEX pattern matching

Tags: javascript, regex

I am completely new to JS, and having trouble figuring out how to validate that the *input
via prompt* **CONTAINS** three or more words, seperated by spaces, only alphabetical characters.

This is what I have:

```
var p = prompt("Enter a phrase:", "");
var phr = p.search(/^[^0-9][2,3]$/);

  if(phr != 0)
{
   alert("invalid");return
}
else{document.write("phr");
```

Comment: @Floris- `\w` will match digits also. Besides that your expression will require, for a string three character long, to have an additional space.

Comment: @edi_allen - you were right. Don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `prompt CONTAINS three or more words, seperated by spaces, only alphabetical characters.`

You can try this regex:

```
/^[a-z]+( +[a-z]+){2,}$/i
```

Comment: `^/` should probably be `/^`, isn't it?

Comment: @Boaz: Thanks so much, it was a typo, fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
if (/^([a-z]+\s+){2,}[a-z]+$/i.test(p))
```

Explanation:

- `[a-z]` = alphabetic character
- `[a-z]+` = 1 or more alphabetic character, i.e. a word
- `[a-z]+\s+` = word followed by 1 or more whitespace characters
- `([a-z]+\s+)` = at least 2 words with whitespace after each
- `([a-z]+\s+){2,}[a-z]+` = the above followed by 1 more word
- `^([a-z]+\s+){2,}[a-z]+$` = anchor the above to the beginning and end of the string

The `i` modifier makes it case-insensitive, so it will allow uppercase letters as well.